# Compile time jumps when moving from Flex Build to Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, compilation, flash-builder

I moved from using the Flex Builder 3 IDE to Flash Builder a couple weeks ago and have noticed a ridiculous jump in compile times with the same project.  It almost seems like every time I build it does a clean build.  The project I am working with is pretty big, but when it takes more than 4 mins to build, something is wrong.  I tried adding more memory to eclipse and all the tricks I could find on the web but the compile time never really changed.

I am running under Windows 7 32bit, and I get the same performance from the plugin and stand alone version of the IDE.

Anyone know why and how I can speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same SDK?  Changes in SDK could affect performance; although I would expect that later SDKs would have better performance than earlier SDKs.

A Change in JVM could affect performance, so check that.  I also know that some people have seen performance improvements based on settings for the JVM arguments in the eclipse.ini file.  Usually they use [Xms and Xmx](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/performance/jvm-tuning.xtp).  Although I never did that on my new machine, so can't check specifics.  Experiment w/ values.  Here is a [nice writeup](http://polygeek.com/2496_flex_improve-flash-builders-performance-by-updating-your-eclipse-ini-file) specific to Flex Builder.

You can also try enabling [incremental compilation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_20.html).

Comment: I believe incremental is enabled by default when using Flex / Flash Builder.

Comment: Which SDK?  The Flex SDK or the JVM?

Comment: Well, then the other part of my answer was to see if you had changed JVMs that Eclipse uses.  That is another possible source of performance issues.  Have you checked that?  Did the JVM change?  Have you tried specifying the Xms or Xmx values in your Flash Builder ini file

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but are you by any chance working on a PC which has a remote profile so that your workspace files aren't stored locally?  If so try switching to a different workspace created in a folder that's definitely local (nothing under /documents and settings etc).

**Edit:**
If that's the issue you'd have to go into the FB install folder's configuration directory to edit config.ini and change any user.home references to hard coded local paths.

i.e.
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/Adobe Flash Builder
becomes
osgi.instance.area.default=C:/somevalidpath/Adobe Flash Builder

Comment: Your project files and workspace can be local, but even if you move your workspace outside the default area there are still large files FB standalone stores under your user profile directory (in documents and settings under your username somewhere, I forget). Depending on how your PC is set up it could be accessing those settings/files remotely.  Still, I'm thinking this probably isn't the cause of your issue. :( This is mainly a concern if your profile space is limited to 10mb or so, or if the network is slow.

Comment: Do you, or can you try setting up a build using the Flex Ant tasks to see if that performs any different? http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_1.html